# How to set the path for the Android WebView ServiceWorker Cache?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, service-worker

It seams the path for the Android WebView ServiceWorker caches is inside of `<dataDir>/app_webview/Service Worker/`.

Since this directory is not in the `cache` directory, it is not deleted, when clearing app cache.

Even worse, Android's auto backup feature includes all ServiceWorker caches, which can exceed the backup limit of 25MB.

How to change the path of the ServiceWorker to use the `cache` directory?